# Does app-release.apk have to be located within its application folder to publish?

Tags: android, apk

Can't really find too much info on here about the app-release.apk file.
I would like to publish an update for my application, and I was wondering if the app-release.apk folder has to be located within the application folder, or if the app-release APK file can be outside of the folder.

Comment: Are you referring to an automatic mechanism to upload the APK file to the Google Play Developer Console?

Answer (score 1):

After you generate the Signed APK (app-release.apk) file, you can place it at whichever directory you want, then you upload that file to the Play store through the dev console.

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/113469?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for your reply! That will make it a lot easier to keep track of all of my previous app updates.

Answer (score 0):

*If the app-release.apk folder has to be located within the application folder, or if the app-release APK file can be outside of the folder*

Once you generate the Signed APK you can store in anywhere in your PC file system. Example : Download folder . You just need to upload the downloaded file when you are submitting an upload for your app.